# Display Image with Universal ImageLoader with Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I wonder how to display image if I have a Bitmap and don't want to give as a parameter URL to image using Universal ImageLoader library.

```
 Bitmap img = getDefaultBitmap();
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(img); // I need something like this (for example with parameters to display image like width and height)
```

Comment: if you have  the Bitmap and ImageView you can simply use `ImageView.setImageBitmap(img)` without any loader ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,
     you have to save bitmap and then u can pass that path to show that bitmap into imageview using imageloader.

```
//-- Saving file
String filename = "pippo.jpg";
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dest = new File(sd, filename);

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
try {
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

//-- show bitmap to imageview
imageLoader.displayImage(dest.getAbsolutePath(), imageView);
```

Comment: what a waste of time ... if he has imageview and bitmap then there is no need for loader at all ...

Comment: pls change the compress line .PNG to .JPEG.. then the above code is working fine..