# android recycler view adapters, viewpagers, databases, bitmaps and out of memory errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, arrays, android-adapter

hello im loading lots of little images (ex: 180x180 10.21kb) from a LOCAL database into lots of different recycler views in fragments in viewpagers in tab layouts (nested fragments.) for instance [image: like this] each tab has a new fragment with a recycler view with these little cards and images everything works fine but eventually it all seems to get a bit much for the system and my app is force closed with an out of memory error the error points to my adapters onBindViewHolder, which looks like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    addNewCard cardmaker = cardMakerListDB.get(position);
    holder.cardText.setText(cardmaker.getCardName());
    holder.speechText.setText(cardmaker.getCardSpeech());
    Drawable drawable = new    
    BitmapDrawable(Utility.getPhoto(cardmaker.getCardIcon()));
    holder.cardImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

specifically its pointing at this line

```
BitmapDrawable(Utility.getPhoto(cardmaker.getCardIcon()));
```

this is getting a byte array from the database and converting it into a bitmap here is the method from my Utility class

```
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

can anyone see something that i cant, or that i could be doing to avoid this here im quite new to all this, or is there a different workaround any suggestions welcome

**EDIT**

Thought id try and be clever and have all the images load from an async task, I dont actually know if this would resolve my issue or not but i get this error

07-10 14:18:28.594 18486-18832/ss.sealstudios.com.socialstories D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

i understand it i just dont know what i need to be passing the method to fix it heres what ive tried

MY ENTIRE VIEW HOLDER TRYING TO IMPLEMENT ASYNC TASK

```
public class CardAdapterDB extends    
RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapterDB.MyViewHolder> {
private List<addNewCard> cardMakerListDB;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView cardText, speechText;
    public ImageView cardImage;
    public ProgressBar progress;


    public MyViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        cardText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
        speechText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.speechText);
        cardImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);
        progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarFetch);

    }

}
public CardAdapterDB(List<addNewCard> cardMakerListDB){
    this.cardMakerListDB = cardMakerListDB;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    addNewCard cardmaker = cardMakerListDB.get(position);
    holder.cardText.setText(cardmaker.getCardName());
    holder.speechText.setText(cardmaker.getCardSpeech());
    holder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startNewAsyncTask(cardmaker.getCardIcon(),holder.progress,holder);

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {

    private byte[] data;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private MyViewHolder holder;

    public MyAsyncTask(byte[] data,ProgressBar progress,MyViewHolder holder)   
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.data, 0, data.length);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        {
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(response);
        holder.cardImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
           // progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
public void startNewAsyncTask(byte[] image,ProgressBar progress,MyViewHolder 
holder) {
    MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(image,progress,holder);
    asyncTask.execute();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return cardMakerListDB.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the local db? Are you storing images as blobs in sqlite then querying for multiple images at a time and holding them all in memory?

Comment: @ataulm yes yes and yes,im using greendao to make an sql database when my app is first created and then querying this database at runtime in threads inside fragments, i use the same adapter for each of these fragments and it works fine up until this out of memory error

Comment: I think there's your answer - when you query for a set of the data, you hold multiple images in memory even if all of them are not going to be visible in the viewport at once (and thus don't need to be in memory). Consider saving imgs to disk, and storing the file path in db instead - then you can use an image loader to load the bitmap as and when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the huge number of images causes your app to crash with `OutOfMemoryError`, and unfortunately you can do nothing if your app got this error, it will forced to be closed.

So, all you can do is to avoid the `OutOfMemoryError`, and this can be done by a lot of ways:

**1.** assign a `largeHeap` for your application:

you can do that by adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to the `<application>` tag inside your **manifest.xml** file.

**2.** override the [onLowMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29) method of your activity, which will enable you to take an action if the system feels like the memory is very low at some point:

```
@Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        // you can here remove the Bitmaps or stopping the process of generating images or do whatever you want to survive being trapped into 'OutOfMemoryError'.
    };
```

**3.** you can use any of the Image Libraries to changing the settings of your retrieved images, like *reducing its resolution*, *reducing its size*, and even *reducing its color set*, and the most common ones that are being used in this manner will be [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), for example in **Universal-Image-Loader** you can use it in any process of downloading and displaying your Bitmap:

[image]

---

In your case, you have the Bitmap already loaded and all you want is to use an Image library to edit its options(here we will use *UniversalImageLoader*), in this case you can save the image as mentioned is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26137749/1638739) and after that load it from the memory with the options you gave to it:

```
// Saving image to disk
String filename = "some_name.jpg";
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dest = new File(sd, filename);

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
try {
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

// this is an example of the used options
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inDither = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;

// create ImageLoader instance
ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
loader.loadImageSync(dest.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Comment: this is a very nice answer thank you, im already requesting a large heap through the manifest i maybe should have mentioned this id never heard of overriding the on low memory method so thank you for this, and for the illustration, any idea how to use one of these image libraries with a local database, its the decode byte array (creating a bitmap from a byte array(blob)) @Muhammed Refaat

Comment: @MartinSeal kindly have a look at the new updates to my answer

Comment: Thank you I'm busy for most of today but as soon as I'm free I will be implementing this and I'll update here, thanks again

Comment: sorry I'm confused how does this answer my question? my images are in a database stored as byte arrays, and my app crashes when trying to decode lots of byte arrays

Comment: you can bring each one separately from the DB and deal with it as a single bitmap, which will allow you to use my method in reducing its size and dimentions.

Comment: i havent implemented this as a solution but thank you for your answer i readdressed my images and shaved off any excess size and it seems to have solved it for now but at somepoint i may have to take your answer here thanks for your input

Comment: just to complete this i have implemented this now and it works great save to disc save the image path to the database and then load with an image loader is definitely the way to do this thank you very much for all your effort

Comment: @MartinSeal great, and you are so welcome, and the way you choosed in the final is the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Picasso
 Dependency : `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2`

```
Picasso
  .with(context)
  .load(your_image)
  .fit()
  // call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
  .into(your_imageview);
```

Comment: deghe    the database is local, i tried using picasso but i cant figure out if its even possible to do this using picasso, ive plenty of experiences using picasso with uri but not with a local database any ideas