# how to convert byte array to drawable off the ui thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

This question ties into my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275514/android-recycler-view-adapters-viewpagers-databases-bitmaps-and-out-of-memory) but is a question in itself so here goes,
how would i convert a byte array to drawable off the UI thread, and is there any point from a performance perspective?
the way im attempting it is as part of an adapter and the progress bar works but the images never load and gives me an error in android studio

heres how im trying to do it  (ive never used async task before)

```
 private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {
    private byte[] data;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private MyViewHolder holder;

    public MyAsyncTask(byte[] data,ProgressBar progress,MyViewHolder holder) {
        this.data = data;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.holder = holder;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.data, 0, data.length);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        {
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(response);
        holder.cardImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I'm using this method to call it:

```
public void startNewAsyncTask(byte[] image,ProgressBar progress,MyViewHolder holder) {
    MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(image,progress,holder);
    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

I call this from my viewholder like this:

```
startNewAsyncTask(cardmaker.getCardIcon(),holder.progress,holder);
```

This gives me this error:

```
D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

**What used to work before i tried the async task was quite simple, this;**

```
   Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(Utility.getPhoto(cardmaker.getCardIcon()));
   holder.cardImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

and that 'Utility.getPhoto' looked like this

```
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

This makes the choreographer skip frames and eventually crashes my application with an OutOfMemoryError which is effectively the point in me trying to implement this async task, so if my understanding is fundamentally wrong please don't hesitate to tell me

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

**THIS**

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.data, 0, data.length);
}
```

**SHOULD BE THIS**

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... data) {

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.data, 0, this.data.length);
}
```

but it doesnt solve my underlining issue of out of memory error it just throws it from a different place